# How to replace text to a 'vbcr'

Tags: vb.net, text

Using vb.net and visual studio 2012.

I have a bunch of strings using custom text replacement.
By that I mean that they are all one-line strings using, for example, "&1" to replace 'vbcr' and so on.
I have to take this string and replace all the "&1" by a vbcr.

I tried using regex and stringbuilder replace. Here is an example:

```
finaltext = firsttext.Replace("&1", vbcr)
```

But doing it this way results in replacing the "&1" by a simple space.
I thought that vbcr was the problem but I tried to reverse my code by:

```
finaltext = firsttext.Replace(vbcr, "&1")
```

The vbcr were correctly replaced by "&1" so I don't understand why my original code is not working.

I know it's possible using a long complicated custom function but I would prefer to avoid this solution if possible.

Comment: What prog language is this?

Comment: Swap your "vbcr" for "vbcrlf"  and retry your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, the syntax of [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) states that the first argument is the `oldValue` and the second argument is the one that replaces it.

Also, if you need newlines, you should be using [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx):

```
finaltext = firsttext.Replace("&1", Environment.NewLine)
```

`Environment.NewLine` is easier to read and it also takes care of the platform for you, being

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.